# How does Teamwork... work?

Tags: remnant-from-the-ashes

The Teamwork trait provides a number of buffs when you're next to allies and each rank of this trait increases the range of this trait by 1 meter.

What exactly does this range increase mean? If I have a higher Teamwork trait than another player, does the range defined by my Teamwork trait determine how close I have to be to someone else to get the Teamwork buff or does it determine how close other players have to be to me to get the buff? Let's look at the following example:
[image: Two dots symbolizing players each in the middle of two circles, one dot is inside both circles, one dot is inside only one circle]

Player Blue has a higher Teamwork trait level than Player Red, as denoted by their respective Teamwork ranges. In this configuration, what happens: does only Player Red get the Teamwork buff, does only Player Blue get the Teamwork buff, or do they both get the Teamwork buff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your own radius. When you put trait points into 'Teamwork' and increase its range, you're extending how far away you can be from your own teammate before no longer receiving the buffs.

I've tested this myself and my range is smaller than my partner. When we begin to separate, I always lose the bonus before him. You can see below your partner's name in the bottom right, a little fist icon that indicates you're receiving the buff for being in range.

[Small thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/617290/discussions/0/1636416768328873200/) discussing this too.

> In this configuration, what happens: does only Player Red get the
>   Teamwork buff, does only Player Blue get the Teamwork buff, or do they
>   both get the Teamwork buff?

Only the blue partner will get the buff.